# Automator: Correct syntax for calling an AppleScript file

Tags: applescript, automator

I'm attempting to write an Automator application that will mount an external disk. I have an AppleScript that does the job and I'm attempting to insert it into an Automator application. However, rather than paste in the script I want to call the file, I have the following in Automator:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    run script file "Macintosh HD:Users/username/Documents/Scripts and Automator/mountdrive.scpt"
end run
```

However, this produces a syntax error:

> Can’t make some data into the expected type.

Any suggestions as to the source of the problem?

Answer (score 2):

`run script` also accepts a "POSIX path", you don't need the explicit `run` handler:

```
run script "/Users/username/Scripts and Automator/mountdrive.scpt"
```

You could also add a Run Shell Script action where the content is `osascript ~/Documents/Scripts\ and\ Automator/mountdrive.scpt`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set myScriptPath to (path to documents folder as text) & "Scripts and Automator:mountdrive.scpt"
    run script alias myScriptPath
end run
```

Comment: Thx for the response. The issue has to do with the separators, they should be ':'

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the problem with the syntax is that the path needs to be separated by ':' as opposed to '/'.
Posix uses '/'
and 
Apple uses ':'